# Is it possible to register and capture notifications outside of the Application Delegate - iOS

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to register for remote notifications outside of the Application's Delegate?

For example: is it possible to have the following events in a separate form and still be able to capture the notification events?

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken

-(void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error

-(void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo
```

The reason I ask this is because I am developing an "extension" for a program which generates Xcode projects and AFAIK right now we can't directly talk with the application delegate form.

I've tried making the separate form respond to UIApplicationDelegate but it still doesn't succeed.

Finally,
Does the registering for remote notifications have to be done in the did finish loading event because I have the following code outside of that event.

```
-(void) registerForRemoteNotificationsWithBadge:(BOOL)badge Sound:(BOOL)sound Alert:(BOOL)alert{

    UIRemoteNotificationType notif;
    if (badge)
        notif = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge;
    if (sound)
        notif = notif | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
    if (alert)
        notif = notif | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: notif];
}
```

Insight would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Urban Airship's [iOS sdk](https://github.com/urbanairship/ios-library) actually does something similar. The [UIAppDelegateProxyClass](https://github.com/urbanairship/ios-library/blob/master/Airship/Common/UAAppDelegateProxy.h) takes the place of the default application delegate and forward messages  to both a [surrogate delegate](https://github.com/urbanairship/ios-library/blob/master/Airship/Common/UAAppDelegate.h) and the original delegate